# 3D engine using SharpDX

Tags: c#, sharpdx

This is the first time I am drawing 3D models in c#. My object Camera is made of 3D coordinates named Vector3. C# uses `SharpDX.Vector3`, what does that mean? Where will this be set?

This is the code:

```
using SharpDX;
namespace SoftEngine
{
    public class Camera
   {
      public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
       public Vector3 Target { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Raises error:

> The type or namespace name 'Vector3' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How to fix this?

Comment: "you [are] missing... an assembly reference." http://sharpdx.org/wiki/installation/

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the `SharpDX.Mathematics` assembly